# Where does kubectl events originate from? How do I export these?

Tags: kubernetes

Where are these stored? Is there a recommended way to export them for analysis purposes?

I'm referring to the data from `kubectl get events`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where are these stored?

If you run `kubectl get events --v=9` you will observe that there is actual api call behind it:

```
GET /api/v1/namespaces/default/events?limit=500
```

You can use api to extract details as described in [the official documenatation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#-strong-read-operations-strong--289).

As for storage, they are kept in etcd cluster. As an excerpt from [discussion about events](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47532) here is relevant part to your question:

```
Kubernetes only use etcd's lease API for creating event objects.
Event objects' lease lasts for 1 hour and doesn't need good precision.
```

You now have two paths around this:

- pull events using api (I'd probably do this for analysis purposes since this is what actually gets relayed by `kubectl` command)
- query etcd cluster (if you want more granular control over data processing)